# Failed to complete request - connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have a backend spring-boot app and a React\Redux front-end app. Via a RestAPI the back-end executing a few heavy queries that might take 10 minutes +/-.

The backend was able to successfully execute all the SQL’s but due to a session timeout spring-boot is unable to send back the response (Json).

```
Failed to complete request: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Is there an option to configure the react app so whenever the process is done on the backend the connection will open?

Thank you

Comment: If an rest API taking 10 min to return a response then there's something worst in your API design and back end development.

Comment: I don’t have any other options. It's a simple SQL but due to the data volume, it takes time. What other paths would you suggest ??

Comment: Even though data volume, you need to change your database design. As per Rest API standards, an API should not cross average 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping connections busy for ten minutes can be dangerous because it is easy to take all of your resources from the connection pool or just end up with timeouts like in your case. Please consider alternative approaches:

- Split your REST requests to HTTP POST which will return HTTP 202 status with some identifier(The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed) and then try to do HTTP GET after some time/action when processing is done
- Use web sockets, where you can subscribe to some topic or queue and wait until the task is done on the backend. After that, you can send the message from the backend, and your frontend app will get it from the subscription.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I like the second option and I think it actually what I need. Since I am using Oracle, will spring data include also reactive support for this database type?

Comment: Looks like web socket will be a problem with Oracle. Do you have any good references for the split option?